# Background color is not changing on mouseover, mouseout event

Tags: html, html-table, background-color

I have a simple html table layout as:

```
<table class="grid">
<thead>
<tr><th>1st Col</th><th>2nd Col</th><th>3rd Col</th><th>4th Col</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaaa</td><td>bbbb</td><td>cccc</td><td>dddd</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAaa</td><td>BBbb</td><td>CCcc</td><td>DDdd</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaAA</td><td>bbBB</td><td>ccCC</td><td>ddDD</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The background color of this table is defined in css:

```
table.grid > * > tr > * {
  border-right: 4px groove #D1D1D1;
  border-bottom: 4px groove #D1D1D1;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

So, on load, the rows of this table are light yellow (#FFFFCC). While a user moves their cursor over the table, I want the color of the respective rows to change to give a highlight effect. I have used following jquery code to accomplish the highlighting effect:

```
$("body").on("mouseover mouseout",".grid > tbody > tr", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

and the highlight class is in again in the same css file:

```
tr.highlight{
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: green;
}
```

I found that, except for the background-color of the respective row, the font style and font color is changing. So the code is working to some extent but not completely.

But if I remove the background-color style from css, i.e, on load the table is white, the background-color of rows is changing to green while moving cursor over it:

```
table.grid > * > tr > * {
  border-right: 4px groove #D1D1D1;
  border-bottom: 4px groove #D1D1D1;
  padding: 0;
  //background-color: #FFFFCC;<--- I have to remove this line
}
```

Do you have any idea, how can I change the rows color if it is already given a background-color on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those CSS selectors are really bad, and you don't need JS for the hover effect. Simplify it.

`tr.highlight` won't affect anything since you're setting the background color to the children of `tr`, not the `tr` itself.

Also, read about [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

---

Here's a working code:

```css
table.grid tr td {
  border-right: 4px groove #D1D1D1;
  border-bottom: 4px groove #D1D1D1;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}

table.grid tr:hover td{
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid">
<thead>
<tr><th>1st Col</th><th>2nd Col</th><th>3rd Col</th><th>4th Col</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaaa</td><td>bbbb</td><td>cccc</td><td>dddd</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAaa</td><td>BBbb</td><td>CCcc</td><td>DDdd</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaAA</td><td>bbBB</td><td>ccCC</td><td>ddDD</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps me a lot.

Comment: But if the row has any `input[type="text"]` element, then the background of that/those input elements are not changing of that rows. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: In that case you can write an additional selector (`table.grid tr:hover td, table.grid tr:hover input`), or use a wildcard (`table.grid tr:hover *`)